# Using javax/json, how can I add elements to an existing JsonArray?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I read a JSON array from a file but I'd like to add additional entries into the array. How would I go about doing this using the javax.json library?

```
private String getJson(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(fis);
    // Place where I'd like to get more entries.

    String temp = jsonReader.readArray().toString();
    jsonReader.close();
    fis.close();
    return temp;
}
```

Preview of the JSON format of the file:

```
[
    {"imgOne": "test2.png", "imgTwo": "test1.png", "score": 123123.1},
    {"imgOne": "test2.png", "imgTwo": "test1.png", "score": 1234533.1}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. [`JsonArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) (and the other value types) is meant to be immutable. The javadoc states

> `JsonArray` represents an immutable JSON array (an ordered sequence of
>   zero or more values). It also provides an unmodifiable list view of
>   the values in the array.

The long answer is to create a new `JsonArray` object by copying over the values from the old one and whatever new values you need.

For example

```
// Place where I'd like to get more entries.
JsonArray oldArray = jsonReader.readArray();
// new array builder
JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
// copy over old values
for (JsonValue value : oldArray) {
    builder.add(value);
}
// add new values
builder.add("new string value");
// done
JsonArray newArray = builder.build();
```